# How to compress files in .NET 1.1

Tags: .net, compression

I need to compress files in [*.zip] format in .NET 1.1. I don't want to use SharpZip for compression as I got random errors - "Access Denied" - when running it in .NET 1.1.

SharptZip will work properly only if I put the assembly on the GAC - which is not an option in my project. This is the problem. Check this: http://forums.asp.net/p/1139901/1839049.aspx#1839049

Comment: I followed the thread in the URI you provided.  Do you not have the ability to put a strong named assembly into the GAC? per:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b813833

Comment: No, I can. But the problem this is not an option in my project. I don't want to add the assembly into the GAC.  This is the problem. SharptZip will work properly only if I put the assembly on the GAC - which is not an option in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command-line tool for zip. For example [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the [zlib](http://www.zlib.net) dll and use .NET interop to call the compression functions (if i remember correctly, you could get away with just 2 calls, one for library initialization and one to compress the data). Beware that you'll run problems on 64-bit architectures if you use a 32-bit zlib dll and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade!  .NET 1.1 is 6 years old now!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of using J#.Net libraries you should be able to use java zip api included in it.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18495/Simple-Application-to-Zip-and-UnZip-files-in-C-usi) is a sample code.